# What is $alias in PharData::__construct() for, and how to correctly skip this parameter?

Tags: php, phar

The [PharData constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/phardata.construct.php) is declared as such:

```
PharData::__construct ( string $fname [, int $flags [, string $alias [, int $format = Phar::TAR ]]] )
```

`$alias` is documented as:

> Alias with which this Phar archive should be referred to in calls to stream functionality.

- What does this mean, and what would be a use case for this?
- How to best skip this parameter if I want to define `$format`, but not `$alias`? Should I pass an empty string, or `NULL`?

Comment: If you declare an $alias, you can later access phar contents using `phar://alias/xyz..` instead of with its actual .phar path or file name.

Comment: Great @mario, I would accept this as an answer, especially if you can add how to skip it (an empty string seems to work here, but since this is not documented, I'm never too confident about this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$alias` parameter is optional. It's intended to allow accessing phar contents later without the full .phar path or filename. Commonly for self-contained PHARs, you might want to map it relocateable as e.g. `phar://myphar/script1.php`

You can just pass in `NULL` or an empty string to skip this parameter.
 In `phar.c` the primary test before registering an alias is just the string length:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/phar/phar.c#L988